# AttributeRouting generate links with specified language

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

I would like to know if there is some way to using `Html.ActionLink` to set in which language has to be generated the URL of link using `AttributeRouting`. I have tried with:

```
Html.ActionLink("DescriptionLinkText", "Controller", "Action",
                new { language="en" }, null)
```

but it doesn't work. Is there a way to set to `AttributeRouting` in which language has to be generated the URL.

What I need is to put at the top of my website links to change the current language. For example if the user is at /en/contact and click on links to change to spanish I want the same page was reloaded but in spanish language /es/contacto instead of redirecting to home page, for this reason I need to generate URL's in different culture of CurrentCulture to allow to change language and continue to the same page.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use resources for localization?

```
@Html.ActionLink(LocalizedResources.ActionLinkLabel, "Action", "Controller")
```

update:

```
@Html.ActionLink(LocalizedResources.ActionLinkLabel, LocalizedResources.Action, LocalizedResources.Controller)
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't explained well, what I need to localize is the URL of generated link (href) not the text inside the <a>. Thanks I have updated my question

Comment: You can use resources for generating link as well

Comment: But using Resources I need to have controllers duplicated? One for each language I support, no?